# System can't get lock on VG after exending LV?

Tags: lvm, rhel6

So I just extended the VG on my server. Basically, the local disk is 300GB. I initially created two partitions: sda1 is a primary partition, with ext4 assigned to /boot; sda2 is where 74G VG resides (vg is server hostname).

So I had an extra 225G left. I went ahead and created a third primary partition sda3, and after succesfuly creating a VG on sda3, I used lvextend to extend the size of my lv by 1GB.

So, here are the commands I ran after fdisk:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda3
vgextend hostname /dev/sda3
lvextend -L+1G /dev/hostname/home
```

For which I received the following output:

```
Extending logical volume home to 2.00 GiB
Logical volume home successfully resized
```

However, the prompt has been stuck on the last message now for several hours. My attempts to perform an lvscan / or lvdisplay fail with the following error:

```
/var/lock/lvm/V_hostname: flock failed: Interrupted system call
Can't get lock for hostname
Skipping volume group hostname
```

So my question is, do you think my system actually succesfully performed the resize? Am I safe to reboot? Or should I wait around a little longer? This is LVM2, so I was under the assumption that I could perform these operations live while the lv is actively mounted. I know this depends on type of filesystem you're using, but I figured I was good since I am on ext4.

Answer (score 4):

well, it should have gone OK (never had a problem resizing mounted Logical Volumes ...)

for some reason the system has not removed the LVM lock (is there a /var/lock/lvm/hostname file?)

you have not resized the FS yet so it should be ok to
1 remove lock

```
  rm /var/lock/lvm/hostname
```

2 reboot 
3 check the status of the logical volume
4 resize the filesystem

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Save your lvm.conf

Change "locking_type = 3" with "locking_type = 0".
Perform your pvs, lvs, vgs operation,

If everything looks good, then change back locking_type and reboot.